# The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'Int32' for method 'Edit(Int32)'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am performing CRUD operation using linq to sql. But while clicking on Edit, Details or delete it gives me error i.e. "The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Edit(Int32)' in 'CRUD_using_LinQ_to_SQL_in_MVC.Controllers.OTDController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter."
I checked the solution and found that, while running application url didn't get ID parameter. But i dont understand what should i change in my code.. Can you please help me...

My Controller Code:

```
using System;
```

namespace CRUD_using_LinQ_to_SQL_in_MVC.Controllers
{
    public class OTDController : Controller
    {

```
    private IOTddataRepository repository;
    public OTDController()
        : this(new OtdDataRepository())
    {
    }

    public OTDController(IOTddataRepository _repository)
    {
        repository = _repository;
    }


    //-----------------------Index--------------------------

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var otddata = repository.Getallotddata();
        return View(otddata);
    }


    //-----------------------Details--------------------------


    public ActionResult Details(int id)
    {
        OtdModelClass otdmodel = repository.Getotddatabysrno(id);
        return View(otdmodel);
    }


    //-----------------------Create--------------------------

    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View(new OtdModelClass());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(OtdModelClass otdmodel)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                repository.Insertotddata(otdmodel);
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
        }
        catch (DataException)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Problem in Data Saving");
        }
        return View(otdmodel);
    }


    //-----------------------EDIT--------------------------

    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        OtdModelClass otdmodel = repository.Getotddatabysrno(id);
        return View(otdmodel);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(OtdModelClass otdclass)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                repository.Updateotddata(otdclass);
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
        }
        catch (DataException)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Problem in editing and Updating data");
        }
        return View(otdclass);
    }



    //-----------------------Delete--------------------------

    public ActionResult Delete(int id, bool? savechangeserror)
    {
        if (savechangeserror.GetValueOrDefault())
        {
            ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "Problem in Deleting";
        }

        OtdModelClass otdmodel = repository.Getotddatabysrno(id);
        return View(otdmodel);
    }

    [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
    public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
    {
        try
        {
            OtdModelClass otdmodel = repository.Getotddatabysrno(id);
            repository.Deleteotddata(id);
        }
        catch (DataException)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Delete", new System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary { 
                                    {"id",id},
                                    {"SaveChangesError",true}});
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

}
```

}

My OTD class Code:

```
public class OtdDataRepository : IOTddataRepository
{
    private MVCLoginMasterLogDataClassesDataContext otdcontextobj;

    public OtdDataRepository()
    {
        otdcontextobj = new MVCLoginMasterLogDataClassesDataContext();
    }


    public IEnumerable<OtdModelClass> Getallotddata()
    {
        IList<OtdModelClass> otddatalist = new List<OtdModelClass>();
        var myselectallquery = from otduser in otdcontextobj.tbl_MVC_Login_Master_Logs select otduser;
        var otd = myselectallquery.ToList();
        foreach (var otddata in otd)
        {
            otddatalist.Add(new OtdModelClass()
            {
                Srno=Convert.ToInt32(otddata.Srno),
                MemberCode = otddata.MemberCode,
                LoginID = otddata.LoginID,
                OTDPassword = otddata.OTDPassword,
                BBSID = otddata.BBSID,
                IPAddress = otddata.IPAddress,
                ServerType = otddata.ServerType,
                OTDStatus = otddata.OTDStatus,
                RemoteIP = otddata.RemoteIP,
                RemotePort = otddata.RemotePort,
                AllowDownload = otddata.AllowDownload,
                OTDTimeStamp = otddata.OTDTimeStamp,
                MemberType = otddata.MemberType,
                EQ = otddata.EQ,
                EQD = otddata.EQD,
                BFX = otddata.BFX,
                SLB = otddata.SLB,
                Others = otddata.Others
            });
        }
        return otddatalist;
    }


    public OtdModelClass Getotddatabysrno(int id)
    {
        var getotddataquery = from otduser in otdcontextobj.tbl_MVC_Login_Master_Logs
                              where otduser.Srno == id
                              select otduser;
        var otddata = getotddataquery.FirstOrDefault();
        var otdmodel = new OtdModelClass()
        {
            Srno = Convert.ToInt32(otddata.Srno),
            MemberCode = otddata.MemberCode,
            LoginID = otddata.LoginID,
            OTDPassword = otddata.OTDPassword,
            BBSID = otddata.BBSID,
            IPAddress = otddata.IPAddress,
            ServerType = otddata.ServerType,
            OTDStatus = otddata.OTDStatus,
            RemoteIP = otddata.RemoteIP,
            RemotePort = otddata.RemotePort,
            AllowDownload = otddata.AllowDownload,
            OTDTimeStamp = otddata.OTDTimeStamp,
            MemberType = otddata.MemberType,
            EQ = otddata.EQ,
            EQD = otddata.EQD,
            BFX = otddata.BFX,
            SLB = otddata.SLB,
            Others = otddata.Others
        };
        return otdmodel;
    }

    public void Insertotddata(OtdModelClass otdmodel_obj)
    {
        var empdata = new tbl_MVC_Login_Master_Log()
        {
            Srno = Convert.ToInt32(otdmodel_obj.Srno),
            MemberCode = otdmodel_obj.MemberCode,
            LoginID = otdmodel_obj.LoginID,
            OTDPassword = otdmodel_obj.OTDPassword,
            BBSID = otdmodel_obj.BBSID,
            IPAddress = otdmodel_obj.IPAddress,
            ServerType = otdmodel_obj.ServerType,
            OTDStatus = otdmodel_obj.OTDStatus,
            RemoteIP = otdmodel_obj.RemoteIP,
            RemotePort = otdmodel_obj.RemotePort,
            AllowDownload = otdmodel_obj.AllowDownload,
            OTDTimeStamp = otdmodel_obj.OTDTimeStamp,
            MemberType = otdmodel_obj.MemberType,
            EQ = otdmodel_obj.EQ,
            EQD = otdmodel_obj.EQD,
            BFX = otdmodel_obj.BFX,
            SLB = otdmodel_obj.SLB,
            Others = otdmodel_obj.Others
        };

        otdcontextobj.tbl_MVC_Login_Master_Logs.InsertOnSubmit(empdata);
        otdcontextobj.SubmitChanges();
    }


    public void Deleteotddata(int id)
    {
        tbl_MVC_Login_Master_Log otd_deletelog = otdcontextobj.tbl_MVC_Login_Master_Logs.Where(otduser => otduser.Srno == id).SingleOrDefault();
        otdcontextobj.tbl_MVC_Login_Master_Logs.DeleteOnSubmit(otd_deletelog);
        otdcontextobj.SubmitChanges();
    }


    public void Updateotddata(OtdModelClass otdmodel_obj)
    {
        tbl_MVC_Login_Master_Log otd_updatelog = otdcontextobj.tbl_MVC_Login_Master_Logs.Where(otduser=>otduser.Srno==otdmodel_obj.Srno).SingleOrDefault();
        otd_updatelog.Srno = otdmodel_obj.Srno;
        otd_updatelog.MemberCode = otdmodel_obj.MemberCode;
        otd_updatelog.LoginID = otdmodel_obj.LoginID;
        otd_updatelog.OTDPassword = otdmodel_obj.OTDPassword;
        otd_updatelog.BBSID = otdmodel_obj.BBSID;
        otd_updatelog.IPAddress = otdmodel_obj.IPAddress;
        otd_updatelog.ServerType = otdmodel_obj.ServerType;
        otd_updatelog.OTDStatus = otdmodel_obj.OTDStatus;
        otd_updatelog.RemoteIP = otdmodel_obj.RemoteIP;
        otd_updatelog.RemotePort = otdmodel_obj.RemotePort;
        otd_updatelog.AllowDownload = otdmodel_obj.AllowDownload;
        otd_updatelog.OTDTimeStamp = otdmodel_obj.OTDTimeStamp;
        otd_updatelog.MemberType = otdmodel_obj.MemberType;
        otd_updatelog.EQ = otdmodel_obj.EQ;
        otd_updatelog.EQD = otdmodel_obj.EQD;
        otd_updatelog.BFX = otdmodel_obj.BFX;
        otd_updatelog.SLB = otdmodel_obj.SLB;
        otd_updatelog.Others = otdmodel_obj.Others;
        otdcontextobj.SubmitChanges();
    }
}
```

Can you please help me...

Answer (score 2):

The framework is telling you that the link you are clicking on to call the `Edit` and `Delete` action methods is not providing an `int` parameter named id which the action method is expecting to find somewhere in the submitted data. This is usually provided either in the URL, query string or submitted variables.

If that is not enough for you to spot the problem, post your view code specially the section related to the links.

Comment: Hi @JTMon...Thanks for your quick reply... I forget to add "new { id=item.Srno }" in the ActionLink for Edit, Details and Delete...